# How to Calculate the average value near a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line

I am new to ArcGIS ArcMap. I want to calculate the average value of one point ( layer flowline ). This could be done using the value of the point and the values of the four neighbor points ( raster ), eventually to calculate the mean value of them. Is any way to calculate this mean value for each point of a flowline-layer that have totally 10 points,

Comment: It would be helpful to include a visual of what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the Spatial Analyst extension?

ArcToolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools > Neighborhood > Focal Statistics

Comment: Yes I have, but I need to calculate that for each point in the flowline, not for the raster that I have... I am kinda confused

Comment: @user1640255 you could calculate the Focal Statistics first and then use the Extract Values to Points tool to get the raster value into your point features.

Comment: J Kelly and Ian, thank you both of you. I will use the Focal Statistics tool to take the average value of each point. My initial thought was to keep the raster as it is and get the average values in the centerline from a grid with small perpendicular lines on each point. But, seems to create new rasters, having the mean (average) value of the cells, is the best and right way to make it work. Thank you!